# Faster Way To Move Items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I am currently running the *Crash Landing* Modpack in the FTB Launcher ([Mod list here](https://pastebin.com/PNQHYUzF), Minecraft version is 1.6.4). Out of curiosity I am trying to find the fastest way to move items from one location into a Deep Storage Unit. My current solution is to use 4 Transfer Nodes (from *Extra Utilites*) with one stack of "stacks upgrade" and 3 stacks of "Speed upgrades", which is working nicely (a few ten thousand items per second).

However, is there a faster way to transfer items (using any of the mods listed above)? The items must be starting from a *JABBA* barrel with infinite item upgrade (or another source if you are aware of any infinite storage), and enter a Deep Storage Unit.

Comment: 1.6.4?!?!? That version is almost 4 years old! You know that you could update to 1.10.2? https://mods.curse.com/modpacks/minecraft/253026-forever-stranded
I'm not really a modded expert, but I think I remember that EnderIO has pretty good cables. Also there's a mod (at least in SkyFactory) that has something called a "tesseract" or so that is wireless, extremely fast, can send everything and so on.
And if nothing else helps: More cables!

Comment: I hate newer mods, i vey much prefer the older mods from the 1.6 era. In addition the tesseract doesnt appear to be able to move items without the use of pipes, which the defeats the ppint of using one lol

Comment: In that case I only have one answer: More pipes. But as I said, I'm not an expert, I only watched a few videos.
One of the problems of using old versions (apart from missing out on new features and newer mods not being compatible) is that people don't remember what existed back then, so maybe they don't answer or they give you information that you can't use. Good luck that it doesn't happen to you here!

Answer (score 1):

I'm playing Project Ozone Kappa mode and just found out this interaction

If you have Item Translocators and Thermal Expansion, you can use translocators instead of servos to input items into a pipe system almost instantly with the benefits of having advanced filters, like so...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the item conduit from EnderIO mod, it is a lot more faster than extra utility's transfer node and much more efficient. You can stack cables on top of another up to 5 cables in one block, that means with item conduits, they can share the same pathways together without having to find another path that doesn't intersect or cross with each other. This makes it much less redundant in comparison to the other transport pipes.

Just the item conduit itself, wold be fast enough to handle deep storage unit. Additionally, if this is too slow for you there are stack-able speed upgrades that you can put on, the speed upgrades are relatively cheap. I've never needed to use a speed upgrade on a Ender conduit before, but this option seems to fullfill all your provided criteria.